# IndexOf doesn't work as expected: it only finds substrings shorter than 5 characters

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am trying to filter TV channel elements by channel name. I have an html input element, from which I get its value. Then, I iterate over an array of all channel names and if indexOf return value is more than -1 for a given name, it assigns a 'found' class to the channel.

However, indexOf returns -1 if the input value is longer than 4 characters.

Both input value and channel names are in utf-8 (they're all generated by the same php file; some names are cyrillic, some are english). Still, if input value contains only English characters, indexOf works properly. Also, if I log any channel name to console, copy it and paste into html input, indexOf works properly, too.

I can imagine a case when both strings have a different charset, but why 4 characters? And how do I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
function searchChannels(search,context){
        //search is form input val()
        //context is their parent container

        var search = search.toLowerCase();

        channels = context.find('.channel-item');

        channels.removeClass('found');

        for(i = 0;i < channels.length;i++){
            currChnl = $(channels[i]);
            channelName = currChnl.attr('data-name').toLowerCase();
            if(channelName.indexOf(search) > -1) currChnl.addClass('found');
        }
    };
```

Examples of input strings are Мульти (fails), Муль (works) and Nat Geo Wild (works). Channel names are Муль­ти­лад­ния and Nat Geo Wild respectively. Interestingly, when I copy either the channel name from the page or it's data-name attribute from my code inspector and paste that into my form, it works too.

Another example: '1-ый обр' fails '1-ый об' works in '1-ый об­ра­зова­тель­ный'

Comment: Do you have a sample dataset of a failed match?  A string that you expected it to match and the input?

Comment: ChrisG, examples of input strings are Мульти (fails), Муль (works) and Nat Geo Wild (works). Channel names are Муль­ти­лад­ния and Nat Geo Wild respectively.

Interestingly, when I copy either the channel name or it's data-name atttribute from my code inspector and paste that into my form, it works too.

Comment: '1-ый обр' fails '1-ый об' works in '1-ый об­ра­зова­тель­ный'

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is going on, but there is some encoding happening with your characters.  When I paste them into the console, I see an extra character. https://i.imgur.com/x5S7c5W.png

Comment: ChrisG, Eureka! There's a js plugin on my site that inserts invisible hyphens to allow hyphenation (since css hypenation does not work for my language). So there are hyphens in the channel name (like Ка­лей­дос­коп is in fact Ка-лей-дос-коп), that's what you saw! All I have to do is exclude channel names from thу plugin's list of affected elements.
Maybe you can post an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is going on, but there is some encoding happening with your characters. When I paste them into the console, I see an extra character. [image: i.imgur.com/x5S7c5W.png]

Comment: ChrisG, Eureka! There's a js plugin on my site that inserts invisible hyphens to allow hyphenation (since css hypenation does not work for my language). So there are hyphens in the channel name (like Ка­лей­дос­коп is in fact Ка-лей-дос-коп), that's what you saw! All I have to do is exclude channel names from thу plugin's list of affected elements. Thank you!